# ASP.Net MVC2 to MVC3 upgrade-Assembly reference issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, assemblies

I did upgrade my MVC2 application to MVC3 using http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008 updater.

When running the application I get the error as

The type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

How can I fix this error??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a reference to the missing dll. It is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies

Answer (score 1):

By adding a reference to `System.Web.WebPages.Razor` in your project:

[image]